# Universal Instantiation

Tags: quantifiers

I'm a bit confused about how Universal Instantiation works. I read that you shouldn't really plug in any value "a" for x in "For all x P(x)" unless a choice for "a" pops up in the givens but in the following proof they just select any value y. Is that allowed? Or am I misunderstanding it and they got the Y from something else. If possible could you give me a detailed scratch-work of givens and goals.

Thanks.

The Question

[image: The Question]

Answer

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, $y$ is not much needed: it just proves that $x\subseteq A\cap B \iff (x\subseteq A$ and $x\subseteq B)$.

Comment: Well first of all there is a typo. it should be "let $y$ be **an** arbitrary element" as opposed to **all**